# how can i modify a javascript function to operate on multiple buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the same javascript function on more than 1 button , but it does not work. here is:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="buton"><p> SOMETHING</p></a>
<a href="#" id="buton"><p> OTHERS</p></a>

<div id="link" style="display:none;">
    <h1>SOMETHING</h1>
</div>
<div id="link" style="display:none;">
    <h1>OTHERS</h1>
</div>
```

and **JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$('#buton').click(function() {
$('#link').toggle('slow', function() {
// Animation complete.
});
});
</script>
```

so on the first buton it does work, but on the second one ( OTHERS ) it does not work. Why? and how can I fix that? ( I am about to use more than 10 buttons on my original page, so please give me the best idea )

Comment: 1.) ID attribute must be unique, hence your HTML is invalid. 2.) You can set a class attribute for all the buttons and set the event handler in the JS like $(".buttonclass").click(...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDs MUST be unique.

You should try using a class instead.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="buton" data-for="link1"><p> SOMETHING</p></a>
<a href="#" class="buton" data-for="link2"><p> OTHERS</p></a>

<div id="link1" style="display:none;">
    <h1>SOMETHING</h1>
</div>
<div id="link2" style="display:none;">
    <h1>OTHERS</h1>
</div>
```

and **JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$('.buton').click(function() {
  $('#'+this.getAttribute("data-for")).toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: instead of `getAttribute("data-for")`, you can use the jquery `data()` function: `$(this).data('for');`

Comment: jQuery will create an internal cache (`.data()` expando property) after the first call to `.data()` that retrieves the data attribute value. Murder all the unicorns.

Comment: so there is no way putting a general statement instead of link1,link2..... ? cause if I create (for example ) 10 buttons, and then I eliminate the 4th and 5th I would have to modify all of them (from 6-10)

Comment: The numbers don't matter, what matters is that each `data-for` link has a corresponding element with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML `id`s must be unique. The browser enforces this by returning only one result for `#link`.

You can either give them different `id`s or use a class.

```
$("#link1,#link2,#link3").toggle(..)
```

or

```
$(".links").toggle(..)
```